# Awk item from column one, then awk again using the result in column two?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, awk

I have a CSV that I need to sort through using a key provided that'd be in the first column of said CSV, and then I need to `awk` again and search via column 2 and return all matching data.

So: I'd `awk` with the first key, and it'd return just the result of the second column [so just cell]. Then I'd awk using the cell contents and have it return all matching rows.

I have almost no `bash`/`awk` scripting experience so please bear with me. :)

**Input:**

```
KEY1,TRACKINGKEY1,TRACKINGNUMBER1-1,PACKAGENUM1-1
    ,TRACKINGKEY1,TRACKINGNUMBER1-2,PACKAGENUM1-2
    ,TRACKINGKEY1,TRACKINGNUMBER1-3,PACKAGENUM1-3
    ,TRACKINGKEY1,TRACKINGNUMBER1-4,PACKAGENUM1-4
    ,TRACKINGKEY1,TRACKINGNUMBER1-5,PACKAGENUM1-5
KEY2,TRACKINGKEY2,TRACKINGNUMBER2-1,PACKAGENUM2-1
KEY3,TRACKINGKEY3,TRACKINGNUMBER3-1,PACKAGENUM3-1
    ,TRACKINGKEY3,TRACKINGNUMBER3-2,PACKAGENUM3-2
```

**Command:**

```
awk -v key=KEY1 -F' *,' '$1==key{f=1} $1 && $1!=key{f=0} f{print $3}' file
```

**Output:**

```
TRACKINGNUMBER1-1
TRACKINGNUMBER1-2
TRACKINGNUMBER1-3
TRACKINGNUMBER1-4
TRACKINGNUMBER1-5
```

That's what I've tried. I'd like to `awk` so if I search for key1 that trackingkey1 is returned, then `awk` with trackingkey one and output each full matching row.

---

Sorry, I should have been more clear. For example - if I searched for KEY3 I'd *like* the output to be:

```
    KEY3,TRACKINGKEY3,TRACKINGNUMBER3-1,PACKAGENUM3-1
        ,TRACKINGKEY3,TRACKINGNUMBER3-2,PACKAGENUM3-2
```

So what I want is I'd search for KEY3 initially, and it would return TRACKINGKEY3. I'd then search for TRACKINGKEY3 and it would return each full row with said TRACKINGKEY3 in it.

Comment: what did you try so far? and show input and output you want to receive

Comment: Your code seems to work... what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
awk -v key=KEY3 -F ',' '{if($1==key)tkey=$2;if($2==tkey)print}' file
```

It only makes a single pass through the file, not the multiple passes you described, but the output matches what you requested. When it finds the specified key in the first column is grabs the tracking key from the second column. It prints every line that matches this tracking key.

A shorter way to achieve the same thing is by using awk's implicit printing:

```
awk -v key=KEY3 -F ',' '$1==key{tkey=$2}$2==tkey' file
```

Comment: No, regardless of what key is entered it outputs the entire file

Comment: @KevinSouter: It does not for me. I tested it, and got the correct output for all three keys.

Comment: Ahh, I have "s in my CSV, I'll tr -d "\"" those and see what happens.

Comment: After adjusting for the quotes [and the fact that I was an idiot and in my production test csv the second key is actually in the fourth column] it works perfectly! Thank you sir!